# Replacing exterior door sill - making it fit

Tags: doors

I'm replacing the aluminum threshold for my exterior basement door.  I bought a new one but it seems to be a little taller than the original.  It's adjustable but can't go any lower.  If I remove the rubber gasket attached to the bottom edge of the door, the door will just barely close.  But I know the gasket is there for a reason.  Can I replace it with one that attaches to the face of the door?  The current one is in pretty bad shape anyway.  If not, what is the alternative?

Comment: Is this a steel door?

Comment: Does the door open in or out?

Comment: Can you rebuild the bottom of the frame? IE is it wood?

Comment: It's a wood door that opens in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rubber thing is called a door sweep and they come in many styles and materials. It's purpose is to seal off the bottom of the door from drafts. The swing orientation and threshold style usually dictate the sweep. Some mount under the door, on the front side and the back side. Bottom sweeps are often a softish D shape with the crest pointing down. Fronts and backs are often a bristle or rubber blade.

Undercutting the door is an option. If it's an exterior wood door undercutting is easy.

Also relocateing the threshold towards inside or outside may help your situation. If you are able to move the threshold to the exterior and put the sweep on the exterior of the door, the door will not need to close over the threshold.